# Meteor 1.4 and pdfmake

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, pdfmake

I am trying to generate simple pdf from my meteor application. Code in my method is:

```
var fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0] + "public/fonts/Roboto -Regular.ttf",
        bold: process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0] + "public/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf",
        italics: process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0] + "public/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf",
        bolditalics: process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0]+ "public/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf"
    }
};



var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

export const generateProjectListPDF = () =>{

var docDefinition = { content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake' };
var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdfs/lists.pdf'));
pdfDoc.end();

}
```

I am geting error that fs.readFileSync is not a function. File font.js, from pdfmake package. Any idea how to solve this challenge.

EDIT

I am using themeteorchef base, and react-router. I have created font folder inside public folder and placed fonts there.